# Install Windows on a MacBook Prod legally

Tags: windows, mac, virtualbox, legal

I have a MacBook pro retina, and I want to buy and install a Windows 7 on (in a bootcamp partition and/or virtualized via VirtualBox). However, I do not know how to get it legally in a non-physical format.

I could buy the Windows box in a store, but it has a DVD, and my Mac does not have DVD player. Thus, this is not an option.

I cannot find any Windows distribution in a USB drive or a way to download a ISO legally.

My question is where can I buy a Windows license and use it for my Mac.

In other companies and there is a place to download the ISO or installers that you already paid for. For example IBM with PassportAdvantage, or Oracle with OTN.

Comment: BTW, I do not have an OEM license because it is a MAC, so I do need to buy the license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Jamie says is quite right. To buy the key, you can use [Sofway](http://www.sofway.co.uk/) who will send you the key and download links via email. They are perfectly legit, I'm not from them but have used them in the past.

EDIT: Alternatively just install windows 7 by using the links above, then when it asks for product key in the setup, just press enter, which will give you a 30 day trial. Then after the install, windows will ask you to buy windows 7, and take you to their website.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image of it direct from Microsoft according to (this message on their board](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d)

> • [Windows 7 Ultimate (x86)* - 32 bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59463.iso)
>
> • [Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)* - 64 bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso)

I realise that this is pretty much a "Link only answer" but I'm not sure how else to convey this.

---

Other versions are available from [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/cannot-find-digital-river-download-site/66a8439b-0d16-4b70-92f7-1c8486a46ebf)

> Windows 7 Home Premium 32Bit: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso
>
> Windows 7 Home Premium 64Bit: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso
>
> Windows 7 Professional 32Bit: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso
>
> Windows 7 Professional 64Bit: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso

Comment: But did you see the links? they are not from Microsoft but from DigitalRiver. My problem is not how to download the ISO, I could get them easily from torrent or any other pirate service. What I want is a legal way to buy then download the Windows installer.

Comment: Digital River run a CDN for microsoft. These are Microsoft approved links, the forum post is even posted by one of their community moderators. They used to have a page on their site which gave the same links, these were removed when Windows 8 was released though.

Comment: @AngocA - **Those links are legal.** DigitalRiver handled the digital distrubution of Windows 7.  An alternative way is to use a SuperDrive and create a bootable image of the physical disk.

Comment: Ok, these links could be legal, but where do I get the license? CalvT gave me a site that sells the license

Comment: You could buy through the site he linked to or you could buy a physical copy of the disk direct from MS and use the key from that. If it ends up costing you the same amount, then hey, you have a spare disk!